Convergence of weighted quotient of functions
Let $(f_i, i = 1, \ldots, N)$ be a family of smooth functions $f_i: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f_i(x) = 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N$. Let now $(\alpha_i, i = 1, \ldots, N)$ be a family of positive real numbers and consider the quotient
\begin{align*}
g(x) := \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^N \alpha_i f_i(x)}{\sum_{i = 1}^N f_i(x)}
\end{align*}
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x)$ exist? In my problem, each $f_i$ stems from the same family of functions therefore we can assume that each $f_i$ tends to $0$ with the same ''speed''.
I already tried l'Hospital but the derivatives of $f_i$ are not very helpful for my problem so I hope for a more general result/criterion. Any help would be really appreciated!
Edit: I did not want to overload my question, but it seems to make sense which choices of $f_i$ I am interested in. In my problem, $f_i(x)$ is the pdf of a lognormal distribution evaluated at a fixed location $z \in (0, +\infty)$ where the lognormal distribution has mean $\mu x - \sigma_i x$ for constants $z, \mu$ independent of $i$ and the variance is $\sigma_i x$ where each $\sigma_i$ is positive. This means
\begin{align*}
f_i(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} z \sigma_i x} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma_i x} \cdot \left( \log(z) - \mu x + \sigma_i x \right)^2 \right)
\end{align*}
By same ''speed'' I mean that each $f_i$ tends to zero in the same manner, since they are all from the same class of functions (say, $f_i \in O(h)$ for some function $h$ independent of $i$).
Edit 2: The problem when applying L'Hospital here is that $f_i'(x)$ again contains $f_i(x)$ (multiplied by a term that converges towards a constant for $x \rightarrow 0)$ and therefore you are left with more or less the same problem again, i.e.\ L'Hospital does not help in this situation, I suppose.

How do you define with the same speed?

could you maybe make precise what the family and the 'speed' is?

This is a good question, I should have specified this more. I added more details to the question.

For $N=2$ consider $$f_1(x)=x^2, \ f_2(x)=x^2(2+\sin(x^{-1})) $$ Both functions are nonnegative and continuous. For $x\neq 0$ we get
$${2f_1(x)+f_2(x)\over f_1(x)+f_2(x)}
=1+ {1\over 1+{f_2(x)\over f_1(x)} }\ (*)$$ The ratio $${f_2(x)\over f_1(x)}=2+\sin(x^{-1})$$ takes values in $[1,3]$ and   has no limit at $x=0.$ Thus the limit does not exist for the ratio in $(*).$
The conclusion is true for the case when  all the ratios $f_k(x)/f_1(x)$ have limit at $0$ and the sum of the limits is not equal $-1,$ in particular these limits are positive. Indeed, assume $f_1(x)$ does not vanish in a punctured neighbourhood of $0.$ Let $$b_k=\lim_{x\to 0^+} {f_k(x)\over f_1(x)},\quad 2\le k\le n$$ Assume $$1+\sum_{k=2}^nb_k\neq 0 $$ Then $$ {\sum_{k=1}^n a_kf_k(x)\over \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)}={a_1+\sum_{k=2}^n a_k{f_k(x)\over f_1(x)}\over 1+\sum_{k=2}^n {f_k(x)\over  f_1(x)}}$$ The limit of the last expression is equal $${a_1+\sum_{k=2}^na_kb_k\over 1+\sum_{k=2}^nb_k}$$

Could you elaborate on your last sentence? I am interested in a certain choice for $f_i$ and therefore it might be interesting to check the criterion you mentioned.  Do you have a proof or reference that I can have a look at?

I have added an explanation.
